# How to delete .desktop files( shortcuts or pwa or web apps ) in Ubuntu

Tags: .desktop, shortcuts, browser

.desktop files:

[image: .desktop files]

And it's also shown in the app section.

no delete option:

[image: no delete option]

And there is no delete option there.

Comment: The files under /usr/share are system files. You can delete them with root privileges, but they may come back with the next update.
.desktop file generated by the user are typically stored on you home directory.
Except this: please edit your question and add information what is you intention behind removing the .desktop files This will not uninstall the program.